# Как проводить оплату в телеграм боте, если цена слишком низкая?

Tags: python, telebot

[В документации телеграмма](https://core.telegram.org/bots/payments#supported-currencies) указано, что минимальная цена, которую можно указать в инвойсе ~80 рублей. Если она будет меньше - кидает ошибку:

`telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: CURRENCY_TOTAL_AMOUNT_INVALID`

Как реализовать оплату товара, для которого цена будет меньше?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Если минимальная цена, которую можно указать в инвойсе в Telegram - 80 рублей, то нельзя указать цену меньше этой суммы. Если вы хотите продать товар, цена которого меньше 80 рублей, то вам следует использовать другие платежные системы, например, *Яндекс.Кассу* или *PayPal*.

Вы также можете рассмотреть возможность **объединения нескольких товаров** в один заказ и указания общей суммы, которая будет больше 80 рублей.